# How to config awstats to analyse .php traffics?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos5, log-files, awstats

By default, awstats group .php traffics into a single `Dynamic PHP Script file` number.

However, the site's pattern lies in `route=???` after an `index.php?`, e.g.:

```
GET /index.php?route=account/login/valid HTTP/1.1
GET /index.php?route=account/logout HTTP/1.1
GET /index.php?route=product/sunglasses/success HTTP/1.1
```

Is awstats configurable to break down `route` traffics behind a `index.php`? If no, any other tools can do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [manual](http://www.awstats.org/docs/awstats_config.html#URLWithQuery):

**URLWithQuery=[0|1]**
0 - URLs are cleaned from the query string (ie: "/mypage.html")
1 - Full URL with query string is used (ie: "/mypage.html?p=x&q=y")

Related are the options `URLWithQueryWithoutFollowingParameters` and `URLWithQueryWithOnlyFollowingParameters` which allow you tune which get options are and are not used in grouping hits.